# Check if a position found in a string is in anchors

Tags: php, string, position

I don't know if it's possible but I need to test if a position found is inside an anchor `[a ... /a]`.

For example I have this string:

```
Urna cursus condimentum aliquam cursus [a href="/l.-da-vinci"]Leonardo da Vinci[/a]turpis class tempor suscipit egestas est praesent
```

I have a function to find a position, but I must not accept this position if it's inside the anchors `[a ... /a]`.

For example, if the function return the position 48 which is the dot in `l.-da-vinci`, then I must not accept it.

Is it possible?

Comment: One way would be identifying positions where anchors start and end, then checking if your needle's position is between those values. But, just to make sure if a simpler solution is possible - do you really need exact positions of the matches? Because if not, you could simply strip all the anchors from the text and then perform the matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use `preg_match()` with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag which will return the starting position of the match in addition to the match itself.

You can then calculate the end position based on the length of the match to get the range of the anchor. After that it's just a matter of checking if the position is in that range:

```
$position = 48;
$string = 'Urna cursus condimentum aliquam cursus [a href="/l.-da-vinci"]Leonardo da Vinci[/a]turpis class tempor suscipit egestas est praesent';

preg_match('~\[a.*?\[/a\]~', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$matchStart = $matches[0][1];
$matchEnd = $matchStart+strlen($matches[0][0]);

if ($position > $matchStart && $position < $matchEnd) {
    echo 'not allowed';
} else {
    echo 'allowed';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/INCh1